# how the materialized views and simple views work in concerning with foreign data table (fdt) in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, view, materialized-views, foreign-data-wrapper

We have a database in SQL server and, in PostgreSQL, we define the foreign data table on its tables.

Since the index cannot be defined on the fields within fdt, if we can define the view on these fdt's, can columns of that view be indexed?

If we define an index, how do these indices help to improve searches while the main data is, for example, in SQL server.Should we use materialized views or simple views?

If we use the materialized view, is the SQL server data transmitted to PostgreSQL and then the PostgreSQL create indices on the transferred data?

Answer (score 0):

You can define an index on a materialized view because it is backed by a physical PostgreSQL table.

You cannot define an index on a view, because the view is replaced with its definition during query optimization, and you cannot define an index on a foreign table.

If you query a materialized view that is defined on foreign tables, the foreign tables themselves are not queried at all.